# Downloading Google AdWords Data

Tags: google-ads-api

My company would like to have access to all of their google adwords data offline.

Apart from the API, or using the API, is there a tool already available that can achieve this?

My company has 70 accounts with millions of active ads.

I will also need to synchronise the data as often as possible.

EDIT: I've come across this tool from Gembox which sounds exactly like what I need http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/ppc/features has anyone used this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GemBox.Ppc for synchronization of your local AdWords data and Google's AdWords data.

Here is how the synchronization process would go:

1. Download AdWords data hierarchy (Account -> Campaigns -> Ad groups -> Keywords and Ads) with GemBox.Ppc. GemBox.Ppc object model internally has a notion of a server and local data. Downloaded data will be placed in 'server data slots' on GemBox.Ppc object instances.
2. Fill local values on GemBox.Ppc object instances by setting property values on those instances with values from your data source.
3. Upload AdWords data hierarchy with GemBox.Ppc. Local changes will be propagated to Google AdWords servers.
4. If you also want to update your data source based on data downloaded from Google AdWords servers, then you need to examine AdWords data hierarchy and your in-memory data source (DataSet or similar), and modify in-memory data source based on downloaded data, and update your data source with DataAdapter or similar mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

you can try Google Adwords editor. AdWords Editor is a free, downloadable application for managing your AdWords advertising campaigns. The basic process is simple: download your account, edit your campaigns offline, then upload your changes to AdWords.

With AdWords Editor, you can:

Work offline on your Mac or PC.
Upload changes to AdWords any time.
Store and navigate one or more accounts.
Add, edit, and delete campaigns, ad groups, ads, keywords, and placements.
Make large-scale changes quickly.
Perform advanced searches and edits.
Add comments for your changes.
Sort and view performance statistics.
Copy or move items between campaigns, ad groups, and accounts.
Export a snapshot of your account for archiving or sharing.
Import an archive or share file and review the proposed changes.

For more details please check it out at https://support.google.com/adwords/editor/answer/2484521?hl=en